# CSS and other changes made won't load when deploying app on Heroku

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment, gemfile

I'm currently deploying an app to Heroku, butit is uploading as its basic version.  It is not showing the changes I'v made through CSS, HTML and other customizations I have made.  Also, I've searched through several similar questions here, but can't seem to find an appropriate solution.

I have precompiled the app but to no avail. Here's what happens when I deploy.  Could you please advise me on what to do?  Thank you!

```
C:\Sites\LaunchPage>git push heroku master
Everything up-to-date

C:\Sites\LaunchPage>heroku run rake db:migrate
Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.3644
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support
 for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them i
n your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initial
izers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonr
ails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required
)> at /app/Rakefile:7)
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support
for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them i
n your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initial
izers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonr
ails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required
)> at /app/Rakefile:7)
Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
Migrating to CreateUsers (20130821031443)

C:\Sites\LaunchPage>rake assets:precompile
←[31mBundler could not find compatible versions for gem "sprockets":
In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
sprockets (2.1.3)

In Gemfile:
sass-rails (= 3.1.4) x86-mingw32 depends on
  sprockets (~> 2.0.0) x86-mingw32

Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only
the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.
←[0m

C:\Sites\LaunchPage>
```

Comment: try running bundle update as it asks you to do. Seems you don't have a correct version of sprockets for the sass-rails version you are using

Comment: I have tried to install the correct version but I get this message instead                                               `C:\Sites\LaunchPage>rake assets:precompile`
`←[31mYou have requested:
  sprockets = 2.0.0`

`The bundle currently has sprockets locked at 2.1.3.
Try running `bundle update sprockets`←[0m
←[33mRun `bundle install` to install missing gems.←[0m`

Comment: @ManuelvanRijn  had to downgrade the gem so now it should be fine.  Thank you :-)